# External microphone detected as keyboard in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, microphone

I have an external USB microphone that I use for video calls on my work laptop. However, I suspect after a recent kernel or other update, it is not being detected as a microphone anymore on Ubuntu 18.04. After plugging it in, I see this in the syslog

```
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB PnP Audio Device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (II) event5  - USB PnP Audio Device: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
May  7 23:34:17 x-Precision-5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11268]: (II) event5  - USB PnP Audio Device: device is a keyboard
```

Looks like it's being detected as a keyboard even though it says "PnP Audio Device". I cannot see it in the list of microphones anymore.

On another laptop which also runs Ubuntu 18.04 the same microphone works fine.

How can I get this working or debug further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reboot to resolve this. Apparently kernel updates had happened but I had not restarted the laptop in a while (few months).